# Is there a way to filter out duplicate and on-hold questions?

Tags: feature-request

Sometimes, I'm just in a mood to answer questions.  Thankfully, others have gone before me and weeded out the crap.  As such, when I look at MSO or any of my other sites, there are many active questions with [On Hold] or [Duplicate].  I'm not interested in answering those.

And yet, when I look at MSO in particular, it seems like half of them are already in such a state.  So, now I need to filter those out, looking for a question to answer.

Note, Unanswered doesn't really do what I need either - because even if there is a mediocre answer, on some sites, I can probably do better.  So, how can I stop wasting my time looking at a whole bunch of questions I can't or shouldn't respond to?

Comment: A search for `closed:no` should to the trick I guess?

Comment: `duplicate:no`, `closed:no`

Comment: I was unaware you could that!  You know, if that was an answer, I'd accept it :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using the [advanced search options](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/searching), you can filter out closed questions. Just add

> closed:no

to your search. For example https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=closed%3ano should give you all the newest non-closed questions.

Comment: Just a quick elaboration: if you want to filter out ONLY dupes (and leave other types of closed questions in your results), we recently added a `duplicate:no` function.

Answer (score 5):

As Bart has correctly said adding `closed:no` will give you what you want, however to answer the larger question;

You can find all the advanced search terms by following the link here;

[image]

Comment: Or you can go here: http://stackoverflow.com/help/searching

Comment: I'd never seen that before.  Thank you!